# How to add src path image to my pdf using Image.getInstance() method?

Tags: java, spring, pdf, itext

Here in my web-application under Images folder pdficon.png image is available I want to add this image using Image.getInstance() method but whaen I tring like this..
**image = Image.getInstance("images/pdficon.png");**

Here it showing Exception is 
**IOException :: C:\Users\Developpc\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\bin\images\pdficon.png (The system cannot find the path specified)**

So,what I need to do....

Comment: where is your code? there's no way to tell anything from this snippet.

Comment: and even saying under your web applications folder is extremely vague

Comment: I am giving only "images/pdficong.png" path but how it add this location C:\Users\Developpc\Downloads\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\bin\

Comment: actually images folder not in bin folder of wildfy server it is available in deployments folder

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: else if(src.startsWith("pdfdata")) {
                image = Image.getInstance(String.format("pdficon.png"));
                image.scalePercent(100f);
            }

Comment: please add the actual class rather than part of a conditional to the actual question. it's completely unreadable in the comment section.

Answer (score -1):

Signup for some free image hosting account and upload your image. After uploading your image you can get the URL of the image and put that URL for image.getInstanceMethod.

Image img = Image.getInstance(IMG_URL);
If you are using that image multiple times then create an string constant and use that.